# Variable expansion in comments

Tags: bash, preprocessor, sungridengine

Is it possible to expand variables in comments inside a bash script?

I want to write a script to feed into [SGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Grid_Engine). The `qsub` syntax allows me to pass additional parameters to the grid engine using lines inside the bash script which begin with `#$`. For example,

```
#$ -q all.q
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -V
#$ -m beas
#$ -o run_20120103.out
```

What I want is that the `-o` parameter is dynamically set to a variable, say `$1`. So I would naively write

```
#$ -o run_${1}.out
```

However, since the line starts with a `#`, bash ignores it and the variable `$1` is not expanded.

Any ideas? Some bash preprocessor? Some other way?

**EDIT** I just chose `$1` as an example. It could just as well be `$FOO` or `$BAR`.

Comment: What is determining the value of ${1} ? 
Are you doing a for cycle to load different jobs on the cluster/grid?

Comment: In that case you can simply call qsub with the option -o inside your loop instead of putting #$ -o inside the script fed into qsub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable expansion happens in shell memory, it doesn't affect the file. Therefore, it doesn't matter what bash expands.

Instead, you can probably generate the script to be run on the fly, with everything expanded in place:

```
cat << EOF | qsub [options] -
#$ -o run_$1.out
cmds
EOF
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what this script does step by step? I tried testing it but as I have no idea what the behavior should be and I am not getting the behavior I expect it's quite useless

Comment: @Gullydwarf This script is not a complete or self contained example. It merely illustrates a syntactic structure for expanding variables in text before feeding it to qsub.

Comment: Could you expand it to be?
I think this might be what I am looking for to expand a variable walltime for my jobs. There is no option like -o for walltime in qsub is there? That would make it so much easier :p

Edit: I think I found it, -l can also be used as option to qsub, where I think I can pass the walltime. Testing now

Comment: Unfortunately I only know bash, not qsub. If you know how to invoke qsub and what the input should be, I'll be happy to help out with the bash required to make that happen.

Comment: The input for qsub is a bash job script :)

Comment: Well, if you know how to invoke qsub and what that bash job script should look like...

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more SGE specific than the accepted answer, just redirect the standard output of `qsub` and parse the job id. You can then use this to alter the job name via `qalter`.

Here's a sample of a script I used to submit and modify jobs like this.

```
 for a in $args;
 do 
    qsub submission_script $a 1> job.txt
    jid=$(cat job.txt | tr -dc '0-9' | cut -c -6)
    qalter $jid -N $a
 done
```

I'm certain that there are more idiomatic ways to do this, but this is a first go.

This approach allows `submission_script` to have it's own arguments. It also allows you to programmatically alter other job characteristics, not just the name.

Answer (score -2):

I am also using the `qsub` command in SGE to generate different output or error logs. For example, if I would like to include the `TASK_ID` in the script, instead of doing

```
#$ -o run_${TASK_ID}.out
```

Write it without the paretheses will do the trick:

```
#$ -o run_$TASK_ID.out
```

Comment: No, it doesn't do the trick. You get a file called run_$TASK_ID.out, the variable hasn't be replaced by its value